# Расхэширование пароля

Tags: c#

Доброй ночи, форумчане! Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне расхэшировать пароль, чтобы проверить верно ли его пользователь ввёл? Ниже приведён пример хэширования, а как мне получить обратную функцию? Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```
        string password = @"1234abcd";

        byte[] encodedPassword = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(password);

        byte[] hash = ((HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(encodedPassword);

        string encoded = BitConverter.ToString(hash)
           .Replace("-", string.Empty)
           .ToLower();
```

Условно как мне из строки ef73781effc5774100f87fe2f437a435 получить 1234abcd

Comment: Вы путаете шифрование с хешированием. Хеширование не востанавливается обратно однозначно. Идея проверки через хеширование, являетяс хеширование исходных данных и проверка самих хешей.

Comment: проще говооря чтобы проверить пароль вам необходимо захешировать введенный пароль и должен совпасть с хешем сохраненного пароля

Comment: а если существовал бы алгоритм то все админы уже давно востановили все пароли из баз данных

Comment: Как уже сказал Aziz, это практически невозможно. Однако, вы можете попытать счастья с [радужными таблицами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Радужная_таблица)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Условно как мне из строки ef73781effc5774100f87fe2f437a435 получить 1234abcd

Никак, это условно невозможно. Хэш необратим, это его главная фишка.

Но на самом деле пароль расхэшировать не нужно, и не требуется. Это потому что у хэша есть одно важное свойство: из одного и того же пароля всегда получится один и тот же хэш.

Хэш это такая формула

```
хэш_пароля = хэш_функция(открытый_пароль)
```

Вы применяете эту формулу, чтобы получить и сохранить хэш пароля.

Теперь, как же введенный пароль сравнить с сохраненным? Очень просто, примените к нему эту же формулу.

```
хэш_введенного_пароля = хэш_функция(введенный_пароль)
```

И сравните 2 хэша

```
если (хэш_введенного_пароля == хэш_пароля)
    введенный пароль правильный
иначе
    введенный пароль неправильный
```

---

P.S. MD5 - слабый и устаревший хэш, используйте либо просто SHA256, либо RFC 2898 на базе SHA256, но первого вполне достаточно, если уж вас изначально MD5 устраивал.

Пример кода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string password = "1234";
    byte[] hash = HashPassword(password);
    Console.WriteLine($"Хэш пароля: {HashToString(hash)}");
    Console.Write("Введите пароль: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] inputHash = HashPassword(input);
    if (hash.SequenceEqual(inputHash))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Пароль верный");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Пароль неверный");
    }
}

static byte[] HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    return SHA256.HashData(bytes);
}

static string HashToString(byte[] hash)
{
    return Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToLower();
}

static byte[] HashFromString(string text)
{
    return Convert.FromHexString(text);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Хэш пароля: 03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4
Введите пароль: 1234
Пароль верный
```

Comment: "из одного и того же пароля всегда получится один и тот же хэш." - Спасибо огромное! Вообще не представлял как работать с хэш паролей и как их сравнивать
Отдельная благодарность за то, как использовать SHA256
@aepot - вам просто цены нет!!!