# Как реализовать сессию в Windows Forms ? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

я написал форму авторизации и приложение на Windows Forms(сервер локальный(MAMP), база данных MySQL) [по этому гайду](https://youtu.be/pNTQy48Pafc), которое показывается при успешной авторизации, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне лучше всего реализовать подобие сессий в php, чтобы пользователю не пришлось по 200 раз вводить данные.
Поскольку это не веб-приложение, думаю можно сделать это с помощью конфигов и %appdata%, с точки зрения безопасности - пойдёт, но реализовать у меня знаний c# не хватит

На всякий случай код:
**LoginForm.cs**

```
 namespace StormCat
{
    public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void close_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            close.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(148, 140, 166);
        }

        private void close_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            close.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(160, 0, 0);
            
        }
        private void tray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void tray_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tray.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(148, 140, 166);
        }

        private void tray_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tray.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 64, 0);
        }

        private void login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String loginUser = login_textbox.Text;
            String passwordUser = password_textbox.Text;

            DB db = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `password` = @uP", db.getConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordUser;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);



            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                this.Hide();
                StormCat loginApp = new StormCat();
                loginApp.logged_username.Text = loginUser;
                loginApp.Show();
                
            }
                

        }
    }
}
```

**StormCat.cs**

```
namespace StormCat
{
    public partial class StormCat : Form
    {
        public StormCat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void close_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            close.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(148, 140, 166);
        }

        private void close_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            close.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(160, 0, 0);

        }

        private void tray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void tray_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tray.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(148, 140, 166); 
        }

        private void tray_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tray.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 64 ,0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы запоминался Login & Password только на время, пока выполняется программа?

Comment: @Виктор, нет, чтобы запоминалась навсегда в памяти диска, чтобы при следующем запуске не вписывать данные, и появилась форма StormCat.cs, а не LoginForm.cs

Comment: У Вас же база есть - зачем что-то придумывать. Там и сохраняйте

Comment: @Виктор , мне кажется на компьютере пользователя реализовать будет проще и удобнее

Comment: Ну тогда создайте класс LoginData и serialize его в binary or JSON формате. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: Для тех, кто хранит в базе пароли в открытом виде, в аду есть отдельный котёл. :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1464721/373567