не работает система входа в аккаунт
у меня есть база данных, в которой хранится таблица users и код для проверки пароля и никнейма пользователя:


Но, когда у меня в базе данных только один пользователь, код работает отлично, но если появится второй то он все время выдает: "Неправильно введены данные!"
Как мне исправить это?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

2 момента: не надо никогда хранить пароль в открытом виде в таблице БД и посмотрите внимательно - что у вас происходит в цикле foreach(User user1 in allUsers)?  Там, наверное, его совсем не должно быть, а должно быть что-то в духе if (!allUsers.Any(x => x.username.Equals(user.username && x.password.Equals(user.password)))){<ошибка входа>}

Логически подумайте, что будет, если ваша проверка первым проверит другого пользователя, данные которого не совпадают с теми, что вводятся? Вы выйдите при первом таком несоответствие, не дойдя даже до нужного пользователя. Собственно, если хотите действовать по такой логике, то инвертируйте проверку, условно "Если данные совпадают, то выходим из цикла и идем дальше. Ну а еще лучше, делать проверку на стороне базы (у вас даже метод есть для этого, зачем цикл...?), а не грузить всех пользователей в базу и проходиться по ним. Ну и да, как сказале выше, пароль в открытом виде хранить - это плохо.

Пароли надо хэшировать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1464721/373567

Код в вопрос надо вставлять текстом, а не картинками. Например если бы я захотел поправить ваш код и ответить, мне его с картинки перепечатывать надо что-ли? Как-то не хотелось бы.
